# Explanation upon Combination with repetition (Discrete mathematics)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, combinations

In the [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lcVyF.png) is given the formula of "Combination with repetition", but in the question asked, the solution doesn't really match up with the formula, can you please give me an explanation, maybe i am just missing something, in the formula the equation is $"n+r-1"$, though in the solution it is written as "$n-r-1$"

Thank You
With Respect Umer Selmani

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed the point of this exercise.  The formula you cite was for non-negative integers where it was allowable for $x_i$ to be zero in some cases.  Here, we are requiring that $x_i\geq 2$ for each $i$.

Make a change of variable, letting $y_i=x_i-2$.  Note then that

$$y_1+y_2+y_3+\dots+y_6 = (x_1-2)+(x_2-2)+\dots+(x_6-2)\\ = (x_1+x_2+\dots+x_6)-2-2-\dots - 2 = 29-12=17$$

You are then trying to count the number non-negative integer solutions to the system

$$\begin{cases}y_1+y_2+y_3+\dots+y_6=17\\y_i\geq 0\end{cases}$$

Now this is in the format you expect and you can apply your formula, giving $\binom{17+6-1}{17}=\binom{17+6-1}{6-1}=\binom{22}{5}=\binom{29-6-1}{6-1}$, however you prefer to write the final result.